# Excluding 'N/A' answers in Excel table

Tags: excel

Say I have a table of survey results. The scores for each answer are from 1-4 inclusive (1 worst, 4 best). An 'N/A' answer is represented as 5 - misleading when analysing!

I want to use a function in the final column that calculates the respondent's overall score for the survey. Rather than replacing 5 with 0 for a 'N/A' answer, I'd like to simply exclude that number altogether, and also exclude it from the overall maximum.

**For example, say my maximum overall survey score was 80**. If someone puts 'N/A' for one question, then I'd like their score to be `n / 76`, rather than `n / 80`.

Any suggestions? Feel free to ask for clarification if needed.

EDIT: See below for example image. I'm trying to get Overall Score / Max Score.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of spreadsheet?

Comment: What is n? And how did you come up with 76 and 80?

Comment: @ShrikantShete I did say 'For example, say my maximum overall survey score was 80'

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with the available functions I stumbled across 2: `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF`.

As above, I'm trying to calculate Overall Score / Max Score.

So the formula I use is:

`=SUMIF(range, "<5") / (COUNTIF(range, "<5")*4)`

Stepping through the function:

- `=SUMIF(range, "<5")` calculates the overall score (any number less than 5, ignores text)
- `(COUNTIF(range, "<5")*4)` calculates the number of cells with numbers less than 5, ignores text. I then multiply this by the maximum score for a given question (which was 4). This gives me the maximum score possible given the number of 'N/A' responses.

Finally I divide the former by the latter and get the score I'm looking for. Hope this helps!